# Как удалить или составить новый словарь, в Python 3 по одинаковым символам в ключах

Tags: python-3.x

Существует словарь с вложенными словарями, как можно удалить из текущего словаря вложенные словари по частям ключей `"_RUB"`, или сделать новый словарь с выборкой по одинаковым символам `"_RUB"` в ключах.

```
kurs = { "USD_RUB": {
    "buy_price": "6750",
    "sell_price": "6766"

  },
  "UAH_RUB": {
    "buy_price": "5863",
    "sell_price": "5894"

  },
  "RON_EUR": {
    "buy_price": "425848",
    "sell_price": "427721"

  },
  "USD_RON": {
    "buy_price": "175017",
    "sell_price": "175390"

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалить из текущего словаря вложенные словари по частям ключей "_RUB":

```
kurs = {key: val for key, val in kurs.items() if not '_RUB' in key}
```

или сделать новый словарь с выборкой по одинаковым символам "_RUB" в ключах:

```
new_kurs = {key: val for key, val in kurs.items() if '_RUB' in key}
```

Comment: Тогда, `if not '_RUB' in key}` -> `if '_RUB' not in key}`